# How can I programmatically add uielements to canvas in Silverlight 4?

Tags: canvas, silverlight-4.0, uielement

How can I programmatically add `UIElement`s to canvas in Silverlight 4?

But nothing happens. When I check for the existence of the image it is there
but nothing shows.

**wtf?**

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "Button";
Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 450);
Canvas.SetTop(btn, 100);
Canvas1.Resources.Add("btn1", btn);
Canvas1.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Children`, not `Resources`.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "Button";
Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 450);
Canvas.SetTop(btn, 100);
Canvas1.Children.Add(btn);
```